# Box-shadow over image?

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G5FaQ/

I have an image contained in a div.  A div just next to said image has a box shadow.  I want the box-shadow of the div to overlap the image, so it looks like the image is a part of the div it is in, rather than appearing to hover strangely over it.  I tried z-index, as you'll see in the fiddle, but that seems to have failed.

HTML:

```
<body>

<nav id="navigation">
    <img src="http://web.fildred.com/media/images/blank_logo.jpg" height="150px" width="250px" alt="logo">
</nav>

<div id="content_wrapper">
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="content" -->
<section id="content">
    Content.
</section>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #ffd288;    
}

/*Nav*/
#navigation {
    width:100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

.logo {
    z-index: 1; 
}

/*Content Section*/
#content {
    background: #393951;
    height: 2000px;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you almost had it! all you need to do is add position absolute or relative to the container! Position relative if you want the container to act like a normal dom element, or absolute if you want it to float freely!

```
position:relative;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G5FaQ/1/

Good luck and let me know if you have another question  :)

Comment: I'll be accepting this when I can, because I think this one came in first.  Also, positive attitude :).  Thanks to brbcoding, too, though.  Can't believe I was so silly.

Comment: Oh I think brcoding came in before me by 10 seconds :) but thank you!

Comment: `position: fixed` will also do the trick, if you're wanting the `nav` to stay in place when scrolling

Answer (score 3):

Give your `#navigation` id some kind of positioning... That's a requirement to use `z-index`..

```
#navigation {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/G5FaQ/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 position: absolute;
```

in the content div and then manage it using right and left..